# PHP tag system with preg_match and foreach

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, keyword-search, word-boundary

I'm trying to build this tag system for my website, where it checks the written article (could be 400-1000 words), for specific words and make a string with all the keywords found, from the array.

The one I made is working alright, but there is some problems I would like to fix.

```
$a = "This is my article and it's about apples and pears. I like strawberries as well though.";

$targets = array('apple', 'apples','pear','pears','strawberry','strawberries','grape','grapes');
foreach($targets as $t)
{
   if (preg_match("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $a)) {
    $b[] = $t;
   }
}
echo $b[0].",".$b[1].",".$b[2].",".$b[3];
$tags = $b[0].",".$b[1].",".$b[2].",".$b[3];
```

First of all, I would like to know, if there is any way, I can make this more effecient. I have a database with around 5.000 keywords and expanding day by day.

A you can see, I don't know how to get ALL the matches. I'm writing $b[0], $b[1] etc.

I would like it to just make a string with ALL the matches - but only 1 time per match. If apples is mentioned 5 times, then only 1 should go in the string.

A said - this works. But I don't feel, that this is the best solution.

**EDIT:**

I'm now trying this, but I cant get it to work at all.

```
$a = "This is my article and it's about apples and pears. I like strawberries as well though.";

$targets = array('apple', 'apples','pear','pears','strawberry','strawberries','grape','grapes');
$targets = implode('|', $targets);
$b = [];
preg_match("/\b(" . $targets . ")\b/i", $a, $b);

echo $b;
```

Comment: Why would it run 2.5 million times?  It's only checking $a against each $target, it's only going to run `count($targets)` times.

Comment: If your articles have 400-1000 words, as first thing you should make oposite. Not finding tags in article, but finding words from article in tags. (it will be 5-10x more eficient). With this solution you can also first filter short words (a, an, the, is ....) and dont make search for them.

Comment: Since you only add an entry into `$b` when your target word is found, you could use `echo implode(',', $b);` to display your found words.

Comment: Okay Devon - I edited that out - thank you.

Autista_z - How do I get started on this?

Roberto06 - Great! Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just implode your `$a` variable and then `foreach` with simple comparison using `in_array` function?

Comment: I also second the non-regex approach **but** all you need to do before it, you just need to replace all non-word chars with a space. Use a preprocess step - `preg_replace('~\W+~', ' ', $article)` - and then you can use the `stripos`.

Comment: @Morten Do this, after `/i` in your regex, add a `g` so `/ig` that will not return on first match (it will try to search for all the words and not just the first match) and then instead of doing `..., $a, $b);` add `&` before `$b` so it will be a pass by reference and not by value so `..., $a, &$b);` and for testing, don't do `echo $b;` do `print_r($b);`. Have a look at this regex tester https://regex101.com/r/rBD77y/1

Comment: @matiaslauriti I made the array work now. So far so good! I must be some kind of stupid at the moment, because I cant implode the array? echo implode(",", $b); doesn't work!

Comment: @Morten If you are getting `$b` populated, you must use a `foreach` to go one by one.

Comment: @Morten did it work ? If it did, please mark my answer as correct, if not, give feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) already saves the matches. So:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

The 3 param is already saving the matches, change this:

```
if (preg_match("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $a)) {
    $b[] = $t;
}
```

To this:

```
$matches = [];
preg_match("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $a, $matches);
$b = array_merge($b, $matches);
```

But, if you are comparing directly the word, the documentation recomends using [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

> Tip
>   Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() instead as it will be faster.

---

**EDIT**

You could improve (in performance) your code if you still want to use `preg_match` by doing this, replace this:

```
$targets = array('apple', 'apples','pear','pears','strawberry','strawberries','grape','grapes');
foreach($targets as $t)
{
   if (preg_match("/\b" . $t . "\b/i", $a)) {
    $b[] = $t;
   }
}
```

With this:

```
$targets = array('apple', 'apples','pear','pears','strawberry','strawberries','grape','grapes');
$targets = implode('|', $targets);

preg_match("/\b(" . $t . ")\b/i", $a, $matches);
```

Here you are joining all your `$targets` with `|` (pipe), so your regex is like this: `(target1|target2|target3|targetN)` so you do only one search and not that foreach.

Comment: Thank you. I know that strpos() is faster, but it's not case insensitive. stripos is, but the thing with stripos is that it doesnt find exact matches. Applecider f.ex. I would like to make it as fast as possible, but strpos() and stripos() doesnt work, because of the 2 factors mentioned.

Comment: @Morten You can lookup stripos with prefix and postfix with spaces of your keyword, for example lookup for " Apple ". Its an exact word match.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I get a 2 errors from this: Notice: Undefined variable: b AND Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array.

Comment: @Morten you must define before `preg_match` the variable `$b`, put `$b = [];` If you use my last edit, remove `$b`, it was my bad, or you can rename `$matches` to `$b`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti - Sorry for my missing answer. Check my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to provide a non-regex method, then I'll get into some long-winded regex condsiderations.

Because your search "needles" are whole words, you can leverage the *magic* of `str_word_count()` like so:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b40a7dd67c08a5aac4b3912f9519d4402ace5a14))

```
$targets=['apple','apples','pear','pears','strawberry','strawberries','grape','grapes'];  // all lowercase
$input="Apples, pears, and strawberries are delicious. I probably favor the flavor of strawberries most. My brother's favorites are crabapples and grapes.";
$lowercase_input=strtolower($input);                      // eliminate case-sensitive issue
$words=str_word_count($lowercase_input,1);                // split into array of words, permitting: ' and -
$unique_words=array_flip(array_flip($words));             // faster than array_unique()
$targeted_words=array_intersect($targets,$unique_words);  // retain matches
$tags=implode(',',$targeted_words);                       // glue together with commas
echo $tags;

echo "\n\n";
// or as a one-liner
echo implode(',',array_intersect($targets,array_flip(array_flip(str_word_count(strtolower($input),1)))));
```

Output:

```
apples,pears,strawberries,grapes

apples,pears,strawberries,grapes
```

---

Now about the regex...

While matiaslauriti's answer may get you *a* correct result, it makes very little attempt to provide any big gains in efficiency.

I'll make two points:

1. Do NOT use `preg_match()` in a loop when `preg_match_all()` was specifically designed to capture multiple occurrences in a single call.  (code to be supplied later in answer)
2. Condense your pattern logic as much as possible...

Let's say you have an input like this:

```
$input="Today I ate an apple, then a pear, then a strawberry. This is my article and it's about apples and pears. I like strawberries as well though.";
```

If you use this array of tags:

```
$targets=['apple','apples','pear','pears','strawberry','strawberries','grape','grapes'];
```

to generate a simple piped regex pattern like:

```
/\b(?:apple|apples|pear|pears|strawberry|strawberries|grape|grapes)\b/i
```

It will take the regex engine **677 steps** to match all of the fruit in `$input`.  ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R2G3DD/4))

In contrast, if you condense the tag elements using the `?` quantifier like this:

```
\b(?:apples?|pears?|strawberry|strawberries|grapes?)\b
```

Your pattern gains brevity AND efficiency, giving the same expected result in just **501 steps**. ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R2G3DD/5))

Generating this condensed pattern can be done programmatically for simple associations, (including pluralization and verb conjugations).

Here is a method for handling singular/plural relationships:

```
foreach($targets as $v){
    if(substr($v,-1)=='s'){                       // if tag ends in 's'
        if(in_array(substr($v,0,-1),$targets)){   // if same words without trailing 's' exists in tag list
            $condensed_targets[]=$v.'?';          // add '?' quantifier to end of tag
        }else{
            $condensed_targets[]=$v;              // add tag that is not plural (e.g. 'dress')
        }
    }elseif(!in_array($v.'s',$targets)){          // if tag doesn't end in 's' and no regular plural form
            $condensed_targets[]=$v;              // add tag with irregular pluralization (e.g. 'strawberry')
    }
}
echo '/\b(?:',implode('|',$condensed_targets),")\b/i\n";
// /\b(?:apples?|pears?|strawberry|strawberries|grapes?)\b/i
```

This technique will only handle the simplest cases.  You can really ramp up performance by scrutinizing the tag list and identifying related tags and condensing them.

Performing my above method to condense the piped pattern on every page load is going to cost your users load time.  My very strong recommendation is to keep a database table of your ever-growing tags which are stored as regex-ified tags.  When new tags are encountered/generated, add them individually to the table automatically.  You should periodically review the ~5000 keywords and seek out tags that can be merged without losing accuracy.

It may even help you to maintain database table logic, if you have one column for regex patterns, and another column which shows a csv of what the row's regex pattern includes:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  Pattern               |   Tags                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  apples?               |  apple,apples                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  walk(?:s|er|ed|ing)?  |  walk,walks,walker,walked,walking  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  strawberry            |  strawberry                        |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  strawberries          |  strawberries                      |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

To improve efficiency, you can update your table data by merging the strawberry and strawberries rows like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  strawberr(?:y|ies)    |  strawberry,strawberries           |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

With such a simple improvement, if you only check `$input` for these two tags, the steps required drops from **59** to **40**.

Because you are dealing with >5000 tags the performance improvement will be very noticeable.  This kind of refinement is best handled on a human level, but you might use some programmatical techniques to identify tags that share an internal substring.

When you want to use your Pattern column values, just pull them from your database, pipe them together, and place them inside `preg_match_all()`.

*Keep in mind you should use non-capturing groups when condensing tags into a single pattern because my code to follow will reduce memory usage by avoiding capture groups.

Code ([Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6286c080728d4bbb6b506ec5681670afaf7c1d5)):

```
$input="Today I ate an apple, then a pear, then a strawberry. This is my article and it's about apples and pears. I like strawberries as well though.";
$targets=['apple','apples','pear','pears','strawberry','strawberries','grape','grapes'];
//echo '/\b(?:',implode('|',$targets),")\b/i\n";

// condense singulars & plurals forms using ? quantifier
foreach($targets as $v){
    if(substr($v,-1)=='s'){                       // if tag ends in 's'
        if(in_array(substr($v,0,-1),$targets)){   // if same words without trailing 's' exists in tag list
            $condensed_targets[]=$v.'?';          // add '?' quantifier to end of tag
        }else{
            $condensed_targets[]=$v;              // add tag that is not plural (e.g. 'dress')
        }
    }elseif(!in_array($v.'s',$targets)){          // if tag doesn't end in 's' and no regular plural form
            $condensed_targets[]=$v;              // add tag with irregular pluralization (e.g. 'strawberry')
    }
}
echo '/\b(?:',implode('|',$condensed_targets),")\b/i\n\n";

// use preg_match_all and call it just once without looping!
$tags=preg_match_all("/\b(?:".implode('|',$condensed_targets).")\b/i",$input,$out)?$out[0]:null;
echo "Found tags: ";
var_export($tags);
```

Output:

> /\b(?:apples?|pears?|strawberry|strawberries|grapes?)\b/i
>
> Found tags: array (   0 => 'apple',   1 => 'pear',   2 =>
>   'strawberry',   3 => 'apples',   4 => 'pears',   5 => 'strawberries',
>   )

---

...if you've managed to read this far down my post, you've likely got a problem like the OP's and you want to move forward without regrets/mistakes.  Please go to [my related Code Review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/178931/141885) for more information about fringe case considerations and method logic.

Comment: @Morten I received an upvote on my answer today and thought I'd revisit my old post.  I was able to correct my previous patterns (they were all missing non-capturing groups inside the word boundary characters.  I also added a non-regex method which may prove to be more efficient (non-regex is generally faster than regex, but you'll have to test that assertion with your actual project data).  If you have any questions or concerns just ask.  p.s. My old regex method doesn't say it, but you'd need to "double `array_flip()`" the output array and implode with commas.